# How many users will connect to my Server (simplified)?

Tags: probability, modeling, combinatorics

This is a simplification of question: [How many users will connect to my Server?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71448/how-many-users-will-connect-to-my-server), in which I'm trying to make it simpler and more defined.

I have 5 days in a week.
Each day has 6 temporal slots of 1 hour.

There are 4 working-groups.
Each group **must** fill exactly 2 slots in a week, each one with a working unit.
The work of a group doesn't exclude (and doesn't influence in any way) the work of another group in the same slot.

Each week has always 4 * 2 = 8 working units, which are randomly distributed in the available slots. The only constraint is that the working units of the same group can't fill the same slot.

I define a measure, the *overlap*, which is the maximum number of working unit contained in the same slot. Given the constraint the maximum overlap of a week is 4, i.e. all the groups fill a given slot with their own working unit.

For example, if in the slot of one day there are 3 working units, and there aren't in the whole week more working units for a given slot, the overlap of this week is 3. Also, if there are two days, each one with a slot containing 3 working units, the overlap is 3. Again, if there is one slot with 3 working units and many other slots with 2 working units, the overlap is always 3.

I'd like to calculate:

- P(overlap = 0)
- P(overlap = N)
- P(overlap < N)

Thanks,
   Riccardo

Comment: Clarifications: does slot filling takes place on a daily basis, or is the slot "booked" in the beginning of the week for the whole week, or for some days of it? You write "the slot of Monday" and then "the overlap of this _week_" which confuses.

Comment: Also, does each working unit requires two slots, or it can fill only one slot?

Comment: question updated to be more precise, Alecos is it ok?

Comment: I think so. I will post a tentative answer and we will take it from there.

Comment: One more clarification: when you say "must fill a slot in a week" you mean one slot of one hour during any one day of the week, or, say, "they fill the 10:00-11:00 with one working unit starting Monday, and they continue to be in that slot until and including Friday"?

Comment: yes, I'm adding another clarification sentence.

Comment: Although an answer has been posted, I will try to re-phrase my requested clarification : when you write "one working unit takes up one slot", do you mean one _temporal_ slot (i.e. just one hour over the week), or _one temporal slot per day_ ? And if this latter is the case, is this slot the same every day (i.e. the 10-11 slot), or can it change from day to day?

Comment: Consider only one working group: it has only two working units to spend in a week and one is not influenced by the other. The only constraint is that the two working units are not in the same slot. <Mon(10-11), Fri(08-09)>, <Tue(09-10), Wed(12-13)> are both valid asignments for a working group. The valid assignments are in the form of: <x, y>, where x, y in Slot AND x != y. The only invalid assignments are in the form of: <x, x>, where x in Slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let number of total slots be $n$ ($= 5*6$ in your case). Let number of groups be $m$ (4 in your case).

Think of $n$ distinguishable bins where you want to fill $2m$ distinguishable balls. 
$P(\{\textrm{overlap} \leq N\}) :=$ Probability that there is at most N balls in any bin after filling the $n$ bins with $2m$ balls. Note that  $1\leq N\leq m$.

\begin{align*}
P(\{\textrm{overlap} \leq N\}) &= \frac{\sum_{\left\{k_i: N \geq k_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i = 2m\right\}}{2m \choose {k_1,k_2,...,k_{n}}}}{\sum_{\left\{k_i: m \geq k_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i = 2m\right\}}{2m \choose {k_1,k_2,...,k_{n}}}}\\
\end{align*}

Using this, we can compute any other probability. For example, $P(\{\textrm{overlap} \leq m\}) = 1$. When $2m \leq n$, 
$$P(\{\textrm{overlap} \leq 1\}) = \frac{{n \choose 2m}{(2m)!}}{\sum_{\left\{k_i: m \geq k_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i = 2m\right\}}{2m \choose {k_1,k_2,...,k_{n}}}}$$

Also for non cumulative probabilities, $P(\textrm{overlap} = r) = P(\{\textrm{overlap} \leq r\}) - P(\{\textrm{overlap} \leq r-1\})$ where $r$ is a positive integer between $1$ to $m$.

Comment: Thank you, I can't understand where you take into account that the same working group can't spend two working units in the same slot.

Comment: a couple of question for the summatory in the first formula. 1) do you mean the sum, for k_i from 0 to m, but why do you introduce K_i = 2m? 2) the lower part of binomial is meant to be k_i or am I wrong?

Comment: I do not need to take into account that a group cannot spend two working units in the same slot. This is because, I have not attributed which working unit belongs to which group. My computation is agnostic to this.  For instance, lets say there are 4 units in the same slot and 4 more in another slot. You can map this to working groups such that no group will have two units in the same slot. In general, my claim is that for any assignment of working units to the slots, I can map them to the group so that no group has more than one unit in a slot.

Comment: 1. This is the multinomial formula. $k_i$ represents the number of distinguishable working units allotted to the $i^{th}$ slot of a total of $n$ slots. So, for some slot $j$ where no working units are assigned, $k_j = 0$. The total number of distinguishable working units is $2m$ where $m$ is the number of working groups.

Comment: I'm a bit in trouble with your notation, could you please expand the following formula, using N=2? \begin{align*}
\sum_{\left\{k_i: N \geq k_i\geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^{n} k_i = 2m\right\}}{2m \choose {k_1,k_2,...,k_{n}}}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: (I'm using this page as reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

Comment: ${2m \choose {k_1,k_2,...,k_n}}$ is the number of ways 2m distinguishable working units can be partitioned into n slots with exactly $k_i, i=1,...,n$ in each of the slots. Now we need $k_i \geq 0$ since they represent the number of units in a slot. We also need $k_i \leq N$ since we want the "overlap" less than $N$. Also, since we have $2m$ distinguishable working units, we need the sum of these counts $k_i$ to be equal to $2m$. Any such n-tuple of $k_i$ is a valid solution. We are summing over all of these.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to expand the formula. Now I have only to understand how to generate all the valid n-tuples of k... probably with a software...